# whoosh_backend module cannot be found

Tags: django, search-engine

I recently tried to install haystack with a whoosh search engine. This is to work with django 1.3 on a nginx production server. I've followed the installation instructions for each item (both haystack and whoosh). Although when I try and start the production server I get the following error:

```
Error: No module named whoosh_backend
```

Yet nothing in the documentation covers this, has anyone else come across this problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can result if there is any issue while importing `haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py`.

One such example is an import error on

```
from whoosh.spelling import SpellChecker
```

As a result of mixing Whoosh version 2.5.1 with Haystack 1.2.7 (or likely other 1.2.x version of Haystack.

The recommended fix for now is to install the older 2.4.1 version of Whoosh.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588938/whoosh-importerror-cannot-import-name-spellchecker